# hyperledger fabric .what are the uses of all the different certificates generated by cryptogen

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i have started working on hyperledger fabric.
but I unable to figure out what are the uses of all different certificates generated by cryptogen
thanks for the help

Comment: In addition to Isha's answer, see the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535662/8211613

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, each Organization requires a unique root certificate `(ca-cert)`, that combine specific components **peers and orderers** to that organization. 
Transactions within Fabric are signed by an entity's private key which is **`keystore`**, and then checked/verified by means of a public key which is **`signcerts`**.

**Different organizations** also required to **communicate** their **ledger** so there is a need for **CA or MSP** on an organization level. Within each organization, we can have **multiple peers** so we need certification for these **peers** also. Even peers from different organizations can join each other using **`signcerts`**
and **`TLScerts`** where signcerts for **authentication** and TLScerts for a secure **handshake**.

I recommend you to follow this [link](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

Hope it will help you :)